# JQuery & Timer :: Updating the text of a hyperlink from a webservice

Tags: jquery, timer, settimeout, setinterval, jquery-events

What I'm to figure out how to do is execute a web service on a remote server to determine how many messages there are available to read and populate the text of a hyperlink with the message count.  The trick is I'd like this to be fired from a timer (every 5 mins for example).  Here's what I've been messing with

```
$.ajax( {type:'Get',url:'http://example.com/ws',success:function(messageCount) 
    { 
        $('a.message').text(messageCount + ' Messages');
    }
})
```

but admittedly, I am utterly clueless when it comes to timers in Javascript/jQuery.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the setInterval() function. This will run a defined function at the specified interval. Try this:

```
$(function() {
    setInterval("getDataFromWS()", 300000) // 300,000 miliseconds is 5 minutes
});

function getDataFromWS() {
    $.ajax({
        type:'Get',
        url:'http://foobar.com/ws',
        success:function(messageCount) { 
            $('a.message').text(messageCount + ' Messages');
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Why put in $(function() { ...});?

Comment: To ensure the document is ready before any code executes. Possibly overkill in this instance, but always good practice IMO.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do this periodically you should use [`setInterval`](http://www.elated.com/articles/javascript-timers-with-settimeout-and-setinterval/).

```
//create the timer (and save the unique id returned
//so we can stop it later if needed, using clearTimer())
//This will fire every 300,000 millisecs (= 5 mins) 
//and call the updateMessageCount function
var msgCounTimer = setInterval(updateMessageCount, 300000);

function updateMessageCount() {
    $.ajax({
            type:'GET',
            url:'http://foobar.com/ws',
            success:function(messageCount)
            { 
                $('a.message').text(messageCount + ' Messages');
            }
        });
}
```

If however, you want to do it once use `setTimeout` - you could do it periodically with `setTimeout` too except that you'd need to make a call to set up the timer each time.

The one case I can think of where you might want to use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval` would be when the work you're doing in the function called on timeout (`updateMessageCount` in my example below), takes *longer* than the timeout interval which would cause the next timeout (when using `setInterval`) to appear to be instantaneous since the timer is going to fire every `n` seconds irrespective of whether the function called by the previous timeout is still executing. If instead, you wanted to ensure that there will be `n` milliseconds between consecutive calls to your timeout handler (as opposed to your timeout handler getting called every `n` milliseconds), you should be using `setTimeout` instead and setting it up every time you finish your heavy processing.

**Note**
I see you're using an absolute URL in the example so I thought I'd point this out in case you're not familiar with it - watch out for the [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) which restricts your JavaScript from making requests to domains other than the one from which it originates.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the setTimeout function in Javascript

e.g `var t=setTimeout("yourfunction()",10000);`