# Invoke webservice from javascript to refresh an update panel

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web-services, updatepanel

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to do this,
Heres what I am trying to do:

I have a webpage containing statuses of users I've chose to follow(Something like facebook's statuses).
Now what am trying to do is to refresh the webpage automatically so that whenever a user changes his status I won't have to refresh the webpage to see it.

The status list is a Repeater located inside an UpdatePanel, it's data source is structure of `List<User>` I've created(there is no DB involved). Each user has an unique ID, name and status.
The users I follow is a List of strings containing the IDs of those users stored on the Session.

I have read countless articles about how to use a webservice and how to use javascript yet I remain clueless on how refresh the updatepanel's content automatically through the webservice.

Comment: Do you have extant web services available to do this? If not, then a 'quick and dirty' way of doing it may be to use 'Page Methods'. However, note that using this approach will mean that your method will not be as widely available / re-usable. See http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View7B75C93E-C8C9-4576-972B-2C3138DFC671.htm for quick steps on how to do this. If you intend to use web services it might help to indicate if you have JQuery available (as this is probably the preferred method to make the call on the client side).

Comment: I know about page methods and it didn't really work(I've already tried it) perhaps I didn't specify my question correctly, Edited.

Comment: And no I don't have an external webservice since you can't call an external webservice from javascript

Comment: I said 'extant' (existing) web service. You can call external web services (web services with a different domain) from javascript provided you are using JSON-P or can allow cross-domain calls from your service host. But I'm guessing if you were going to use a WS you would have it on the same domain anyway.

Comment: Aw, my bad, and yes it is on the same domain

Comment: When you say 'refresh automatically' you are probably looking at polling (using a timer). What part are you having issues with - the WS call or the timer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good example of using a timer (for an update panel) here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295400.aspx

Assuming you are using JQuery you can then call a webservice from this 'Timer_Tick()' method using the following:

[JQuery & Timer :: Updating the text of a hyperlink from a webservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5597500/jquery-timer-updating-the-text-of-a-hyperlink-from-a-webservice)

Comment: First answer uses code-behind so it is irrelevant for my case, Second one indeed helped me solve the problem. One thing remains is how to I update the Repeater using javascript E.G: I have both the statuses page open and the page on which you change the people you follow. as soon as you chose to follow someone I want it to automatically be updated on the statuses page.

Comment: I think it will be quite difficult to *immediately* get updates using the above architecture as all you have at your disposal is a polling mechanism. However, this should suffice if you do not want real-time updates. If you do want real-time updates then you might want to move to an architecture such as the provided by [Signal-R](http://signalr.net/) which incorporates features such as HTML5 WebSockets.

Comment: You're right, I've managed to do what I wanted but had to use __doPostBack, because I found no way to rebind a repeater using C# with my current architecture. Thanks :)